# Why is it so uncommon to see electric basses with flat fretboards?

Tags: bass-guitar, construction

I am interested in this as I build my first bass and it took me the whole summer, so any ways to make the handbuilding process simpler, faster and still reliable. Classical guitars have flat fretboards for ages and no one seems to be complaining too much about it, so avoiding to waste those hours rounding  the fretboard seems to be a good idea in a homemade production point of view.

What do you think?

Comment: When you play your homemade bass, do you find it harder or easier to play than other basses because of the flat fretboard?

Comment: My bass has a round fretboard, as I went for doing what the industry does. It envolved quite a bit of work and it's not as even as any chinese bass around, so I wonder if I could skip this step.

Probably, the best answer will come after I build it and test it myself, but wanted to know what other musicians feel about it.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the vertical displacement helps prevent the strings from hitting each other, since the heavier bass strings will oscillate more than classical guitar strings.  It might also be to help with barring, which would be quite difficult on a wide flat board with bass strings.

Comment: @MatthewRead - it's not often the case where barring is utilised when playing bass. The strings are so low in pitch that even two barred will usually sound muddy. There is plenty of space between strings, even on a 5 string, strung with a four string neck width.

Comment: @Tim Hmm, I do like to use barring when I play my 5-string.  It's quite useful when alternating strings on the same fret.

Comment: @MatthewRead - that's interesing! I play mostly 5 string bass, but never consider barring. Possibly it's easier to stop notes (don't want to blend notes into each other too much on bass) with individual fingers rather than slightly lifting the whole finger, or pivoting it? I thought you may have meant using barres to play barre chords...

Comment: FWIW, an acoustic bass (orchestral) has a rounded fingerboard for obvious reasons.  The amount of curvature on any electric bass guitar is far less than that, since nobody ( :-) ) bows them.  I suspect a bit of rounding fits the natural motion of your hand/wrist/arm.

Comment: @Tim - It is true that it's not incredibly common to play barre chords on bass but barring as MatthewRead is suggesting seems fairly common to me. Typically the picking finger will mute the lower of two strings and I find it easy to lift all but the tip to mute the other string. I actually tend to play a lot of chords on bass, when the other musicians let me, and do end up using a barre approach when playing root+minor 3 (10th).  Les Claypool does a lot of chordal stuff as well, often root+5 (as a 4th), and he tends to use a barre approach there as well. Still not incredibly common though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closer the curve of a fretboard is to the curve of your hand, the easier playing will be, but a flatter fretboard should allow a player to play faster and perform better bends.

To answer your question, most people benefit from the ease of playability from a radius, even if only a slight radius, so most companies build rounded fretboards, but from what I've seen flat, or flat-ish, fretboards aren't really THAT uncommon.